# Image on UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have different folder on document directory and have images on each folder. Now i want to display one image from different folder. i have tried but the program is crashe at the line.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
//I dont know what put here for display from sqlite

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *b = [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
NSLog(@"b=%@",b);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"%@",paths);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *imageFileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",b]] error:&error];
NSLog(@"file=%@",imageFileNames);

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] init];


for (int i = 0; i < [imageFileNames count]; i++)
{
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.png",b, i]];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    [images addObject:img];
    NSLog(@"%@",getImagePath);
 }
NSLog(@"images=%@",images);



cell.imageView.image=[imageFileNames objectAtIndex:0];
//NSLog(@"row=%u",row);




return cell;


}
```

Comment: where do you get error??

Comment: cell.imageView.image=[imageFileNames objectAtIndex:0]; When you are using only one image, why are you running a loop to fill the array with images and that too on every cell? Secondly can you please tell us how do you determine which image to display from each folder?

Comment: so, what should i do for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` for images rather than imageWithContentsOfFile

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking at is something like this (**please modify to your liking**):

```
NSString *documents = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

self.contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documents error:NULL];
```

...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.fileLabel.text = [self.contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//  Build Documents Path with Folder Name
NSString *documents = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *directory = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSFileManager *fM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//  Get Attributes
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fM attributesOfItemAtPath:directory error:NULL];

//  Check if it's a directory
if ([fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileType] == NSFileTypeDirectory) {
    //  Get contents of directory
    NSArray *insideDirectory = [fM contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:NULL];

    cell.folderImageView.image = nil;
    //  Loop through folder contents
    for (NSString *file in insideDirectory) {
        if ([[[file pathExtension] uppercaseString] isEqualToString:@"PNG"]) {
            NSString *imagePath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            break;
        }
    }
}

return cell;
}
```